# Need the last entire word form each line from a file in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, text

I Have a file with content

```
./tomcat-6.0.16-catalina.jar
./tom7/tomcat-catalina-7.0.27.jar
./tomcat-catalina-8.5.5.jar
./tom8/tomcat-catalina-8.5.5.jar
./tomcat-catalina-7.0.27.jar
```

I want it in below format

```
tomcat-6.0.16-catalina.jar
tomcat-catalina-7.0.27.jar
tomcat-catalina-8.5.5.jar
tomcat-catalina-8.5.5.jar
tomcat-catalina-7.0.27.jar
```

How do I achieve this in Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' file
```

Output:

```
tomcat-6.0.16-catalina.jar
tomcat-catalina-7.0.27.jar
tomcat-catalina-8.5.5.jar
tomcat-catalina-8.5.5.jar
tomcat-catalina-7.0.27.jar
```

`-F "/"` will use `/` as a field separator.

`$NF` is a built in awk variable for the number of fields, so this will print the last field.

Comment: Now n i want to take backup of these jar files available on system
`code`
echo "`awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' file1.txt`" > file2.txt

num=$(wc -l < file2.txt)
for ((i=1; i<=$num; i++));
do
echo "` cp *.jar /*.jar.bkp`"
done
`code`

but it is giving me error
`code`
cp: target `/*.jar.bkp' is not a directory
cp: target `/*.jar.bkp' is not a directory
cp: target `/*.jar.bkp' is not a directory
cp: target `/*.jar.bkp' is not a directory
cp: target `/*.jar.bkp' is not a directory
`code`